# How can I get Incredibuild to to show Visual Studio C++ project failures?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, incredibuild

When running a C++ build via Incredibuild, the "output" does not show errors.  This is the case through the IDE and the command line build (`BuildConsole`). 
 On the IDE/Build Monitor window, the errors are visible on the [Projects Display](https://www.incredibuild.com/webhelp/#monitor.html#ProjectDisplay) with this error:

> Visual Studio has yet to receive the output of this task.
>   Once this output reaches Visual Studio, it will be shown in the IncrediBuild main output pane.

For automated, command line builds, these errors are not logged.  All logging options to `BuildConsole` echo the [Output Display](https://www.incredibuild.com/webhelp/#monitor.html#OutputDisplay) only.

[image: Copy of the Build Monitor]

*Copy of the Build Monitor*

**Is there a workaround for either `BuildConsole` to log the "Project Output" or for the results to 'reach' Visual Studio?**

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2015: Version 14.0 Update 3
- IncrediBuild 7.3 build 1795
- Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue which is related to a performance optimization feature we've recently introduced.
This Predicted Execution feature can build parts of dependent projects in parallel and by that provide an additional performance boost to Visual Studio compilations on top of what IncrediBuild already provides. With this feature, IncrediBuild executes tasks in an "out-of-order" manner which may surface scenarios in which an error is encountered, but MSBuild's output is not yet available. 
While we are working on solving this issue, we've added a "task output preview" dialog for users to be able to see the task's error message inside the Build Monitor in these cases.
If this intermediate solution does not meet your requirements, you can easily disable the Predicted Execution feature:
On the Initiator machine, open the IncrediBuild Agent Settings -> Visual Studio Builds -> Advanced. Under Predictive Execution section, uncheck the Enhance throughput using out-of-order tasks spawning

Disclaimer: the writer of this post works at IncrediBuild.